# How can I check lines in file with bash

Tags: bash

I have a log file like this:

```
 20141107 14:15:02;10.0.0.5;/home/it/17066.txt;0
 20141107 14:15:32;10.0.0.5;/home/it/17076.txt;0
 20141107 14:16:15;10.0.0.5;/home/it/17086.txt;0
 ...
```

My bash script parsing big log file and create new small log files. Script check small log file and if does not exist, create:

```
if [ ! -f "$path/$name" ]; then

mkdir -p "$path"
touch "$path/$name"
echo "$year$month$day $time;$ip;$file;$size" >> "$path/$name"

fi
```

If the log file is exist, I want to write into that file. I try this:

```
if [ ! -f "$path/$name" ]; then

mkdir -p "$path"
touch "$path/$name"
echo "$year$month$day $time;$ip;$file;$size" >> "$path/$name"

else 
echo "$year$month$day $time;$ip;$file;$size" >> "$path/$name"
fi
```

It's working if file exist or not. But writing same lines in log file:

```
 20141107 14:15:02;10.0.0.5;/home/it/17066.txt;0
 20141107 14:15:32;10.0.0.5;/home/it/17076.txt;0
 20141107 14:16:15;10.0.0.5;/home/it/17086.txt;0
 20141107 14:15:02;10.0.0.5;/home/it/17066.txt;0
 20141107 14:15:32;10.0.0.5;/home/it/17076.txt;0
 20141107 14:16:15;10.0.0.5;/home/it/17086.txt;0
 ...
```

I need to do if line does exist in log file, write. If line exist in log file, skip.

How can I do?

Comment: may you clarify ? Also do you run this in some loop ? writing i mean

Comment: Yes its run in loop. Thats why writing same lines.

Comment: and do you change content of variables in loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str="$year$month$day $time;$ip;$file;$size"
if ! grep -q "^$str$" "$path/$name"; then
    echo "$year$month$day $time;$ip;$file;$size" >> "$path/$name"
fi
```

Note that this is not efficient if the output file becomes large.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this:

```
if [ ! -f "$path/$name" ]; then
    mkdir -p "$path"
    touch "$path/$name"
fi
echo "$year$month$day $time;$ip;$file;$size" >> "$path/$name"
```

Comment: Sorry my mistake, its run in loop. Script run line by line every time and reading same lines. So writing same lines too. Thats why I need to check if same line is exist or not.